# gasEstimate() function shows different value at 2 different states of a contract

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I have a payable function in solidity which distributes the ether to various accounts.
The Ether flow works as Follows

> MetaMask(Ether in M.M)--->SmartContract(goes to the smart contract )---->To all the accounts

I saw that the `await contract2.estimateGas.myPayableFunction()` in ethers.js shows different values when i execute it before transferring the ethers in the smart contract and after transferring the ethers.(it is run on the same function which is myPayableFunction())

> **Before** transferring the eth to the contract await contract2.estimateGas.myPayableFunction() **70116 Gas**
>
> **After** transferring the eth to the contract await contract2.estimateGas.myPayableFunction() **117666.85 Gas**

I am not really clear , why is it so happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gas consumed depends on the contract execution and the contract state. For example if you perform some action depending on the contract's balance it will give you different gas consumption if you received an ether deposit or not.

```
function foo() public {
    if (address(this).balance > 0) {
        for (int i=0; i<100; i+=1) {
            // Do something expensive
        }
    }
}
```